# Facebook no longer scrapes apps.facebook.com

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph, facebook-canvas

I used to be able to post a link like 'apps.facebook.com/my_app' to my business page creating a post with the og: tags located in my canvas page root. This page had a redirect to the page tab (www.facebook.com/my_page/sk=app_12345678). Everything worked fine.

Since a couple of days this isn't working anymore: It still redirects but no image is included.

Additionally, the URL linter now refuses to lint any 'apps.facebook.com' URLs. Says:

> Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own.

Has anyone else seen this? Is this something new? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to have been just another temporary Facebook glitch...
Works again!